# using webservice as alternative to conventional web site

Tags: html

I have been involved with web development applications for more than 3 years now, using c# and microsoft stuff. I am now looking into, and researching, whether it is possible to use webservice, perhaps with Java as the core, and multiple languages and tools, such as HTML5, php, javascript, etc to interact with users. Some of the things I need to be clear about, if this is possible, are:

1. Is such method secure? What are the considerations that need to be taken into account and how can the security part be properly implemented?
2. Are there constraints to what type of interactions the web site can provide, such as sending forms with a lot of details, or long texts?

Some elaborations and examples would be appreciated.

Comment: "secure" really depends on your threat model. If you include what your primary concerns are, I can write an answer on security for you. Are you worried people will have access to data? Low level exploitation (buffer overflows and whatnot) or are you concerned with people using your API on their own website and stealing your user base... or any of the other many possibilities.

Comment: at the moment, I have limited knowledge, so there could be some risks I may have not thought of when implementing the services. Some risks I have in mind are data can be spoofed, data does not reach the intended client or server, and the likes of what you mentioned.

Comment: If you have all of your rules defined on the server, you're good to go as long as the client really has no control over anything. If the client is validating client information and then calls methods, which don't do their own security checks, you're going to have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing are called web apps. They're so ubiquitous you used one (StackOverflow) to ask whether it's possible.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it's possible to make it secure, and no, it's not easy. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security) for a starting point for how to read up on this huge topic.
2. No. HTML5 web apps are extremely capable. If Microsoft can port Office to the web, your online form will be just fine.